Пишет нет связи с сайтом при попитке подлючиться по ip ESP-IDF
Я пытаюсь создать sta-сервер в ESP-IDF, но столкнулся с проблемой — при попытке подключиться по ip к серверу пишет, что нету связи с сайтом:

Код esp-idf:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //Requires by memset
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_spi_flash.h"
#include <esp_http_server.h>

#include "esp_wifi.h"//
#include "esp_event.h"//
#include "freertos/event_groups.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include <lwip/sockets.h>
#include <lwip/sys.h>
#include <lwip/api.h>
#include <lwip/netdb.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include "esp_eth.h"
#include "lwip/err.h"
#include "sayt.h"

int ServTimer = 0;
char data[15];
extern char home[];
char Mylink;

static const char *TAG = "espressif"; // TAG for debug

#define EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID "Danilo"
#define EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS "357357357"
#define EXAMPLE_ESP_MAXIMUM_RETRY 7

/* FreeRTOS event group to signal when we are connected*/
static EventGroupHandle_t s_wifi_event_group;

/* The event group allows multiple bits for each event, but we only care about two events:
 * - we are connected to the AP with an IP
 * - we failed to connect after the maximum amount of retries */
#define WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT BIT0
#define WIFI_FAIL_BIT BIT1

static int s_retry_num = 0;

static void event_handler(void *arg, esp_event_base_t event_base,
                          int32_t event_id, void *event_data)
{
    if (event_base == WIFI_EVENT && event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_START)
    {
        esp_wifi_connect();
    }
    else if (event_base == WIFI_EVENT && event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED)
    {
        if (s_retry_num < EXAMPLE_ESP_MAXIMUM_RETRY)
        {
            esp_wifi_connect();
            s_retry_num++;
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "retry to connect to the AP");
        }
        else
        {
            xEventGroupSetBits(s_wifi_event_group, WIFI_FAIL_BIT);
        }
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "connect to the AP fail");
    }
    else if (event_base == IP_EVENT && event_id == IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP)
    {
        ip_event_got_ip_t *event = (ip_event_got_ip_t *)event_data;
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "got ip:" IPSTR, IP2STR(&event->ip_info.ip));
        s_retry_num = 0;
        xEventGroupSetBits(s_wifi_event_group, WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT);
    }
}

void connect_wifi(void)
{
    s_wifi_event_group = xEventGroupCreate();

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());
    esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta();

    wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&cfg));

    esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_any_id;
    esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_got_ip;
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT,
                                                        ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID,
                                                        &event_handler,
                                                        NULL,
                                                        &instance_any_id));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(IP_EVENT,
                                                        IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP,
                                                        &event_handler,
                                                        NULL,
                                                        &instance_got_ip));

    wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
        .sta = {
            .ssid = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID,
            .password = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS,
            .threshold.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK,
        },
    };
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_STA, &wifi_config));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "wifi_init_sta finished.");

    /* Waiting until either the connection is established (WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT) or connection failed for the maximum
     * number of re-tries (WIFI_FAIL_BIT). The bits are set by event_handler() (see above) */
    EventBits_t bits = xEventGroupWaitBits(s_wifi_event_group,
                                           WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT | WIFI_FAIL_BIT,
                                           pdFALSE,
                                           pdFALSE,
                                           portMAX_DELAY);

    /* xEventGroupWaitBits() returns the bits before the call returned, hence we can test which event actually
     * happened. */
    if (bits & WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT)
    {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "connected to ap SSID:%s password:%s",
                 EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID, EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS);
    }
    else if (bits & WIFI_FAIL_BIT)
    {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Failed to connect to SSID:%s, password:%s",
                 EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID, EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS);
    }
    else
    {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "UNEXPECTED EVENT");
    }
    vEventGroupDelete(s_wifi_event_group);
}

esp_err_t get_req_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    const char *response = (const char *) req->user_ctx;
    return httpd_resp_send(req, response, strlen(response));
}

esp_err_t led_on_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    ServTimer++;
    sprintf(data,"%i",ServTimer);
    char buf[100];
    httpd_req_get_url_query_str(req, buf, httpd_req_get_url_query_len(req)+1);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG,"%s", buf);
    const char *response = (const char *) req->user_ctx;
    return httpd_resp_send(req, response, strlen(response));
};
static esp_err_t echo_post_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    char buf[100];
    httpd_req_get_url_query_str(req, buf, httpd_req_get_url_query_len(req)+1);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG,"%s", buf);
    const char *response = (const char *) req->user_ctx;
    return httpd_resp_send(req, response, strlen(response));
};

httpd_uri_t uri_get = {
    .uri = "/",
    .method = HTTP_GET,
    .handler = get_req_handler,
    .user_ctx = home};

httpd_uri_t uri_on = {
    .uri = "/read",
    .method = HTTP_GET,
    .handler = led_on_handler,
    .user_ctx = data};


static const httpd_uri_t button = {
    .uri       = "/post",
    .method    = HTTP_GET,
    .handler   = echo_post_handler,
    .user_ctx  = data
};


httpd_handle_t setup_server(void)
{
    httpd_config_t config = HTTPD_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
    httpd_handle_t server = NULL;

    if (httpd_start(&server, &config) == ESP_OK)
    {
        httpd_register_uri_handler(server, &uri_get);
        httpd_register_uri_handler(server, &uri_on);
        httpd_register_uri_handler(server, &button);
    }

    return server;
}

void app_main()
{
    // Initialize NVS
    esp_err_t ret = nvs_flash_init();
    if (ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NO_FREE_PAGES || ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NEW_VERSION_FOUND)
    {
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_erase());
        ret = nvs_flash_init();
    }
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(ret);

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ESP_WIFI_MODE_STA");
    connect_wifi();
    setup_server();
}

sayt.h:
#ifndef MAIN_SAYT_H_
#define MAIN_SAYT_H_

char home[] = "<head>\
    <script src=\"https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.30.0.min.js\"></script>\
</head>\
<body>\
    <div id='myDiv'></div>\
    <script>\
        const graphDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');\
        var time = [0];\
        var value = [0];\
        var i = 1;\
        var f1 = [\
        {\
            x: time,\
            y: value,\
            fill: 'tozeroy',\
            type: 'scatter',\
            line: {color: 'orange'}\
        }\
        ];\
        setInterval(function(){\
            i+=1;\
            time.push(i);\
            vaue.push(i);\
            Plotly.relayout(graphDiv, {y: [value],x: [time]});\
            if (time.length>12){\
                time.shift();\
                value.shift();\
            }\
        },1000);\
        Plotly.newPlot( graphDiv, f1);\
    </script>\
</body>";

#endif


Проблема была в том, что на роутере стояла версия защиты WPA2/WPA3-Auto, а надо было, чтобы стояла WPA/WPA2-Auto
